# Response to "Je crois que non"

Tags: expressions

> A: Marie va venir ce soir ?
>
> B: Je crois que non.

If A agrees with B, should A's response here be "Moi aussi" or "Moi non plus"? I know that if B said "Je ne crois pas", then A's response should be "Moi non plus". But with "Je crois que non", the verb "croire" is not negated but the meaning is negated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In colloquial French, a simple reply stating an agreement avoiding the issue you have can be [***pareil***](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/pareil-interj.925077/) or ***moi, pareil***.:

> *– Marie va venir ce soir ?*
>   *– Je ne crois pas.*
>   *– Pareil !*

In any case, both ***moi aussi*** and ***moi non plus*** will be understood as an agreement as ***moi aussi je crois que non*** and ***moi non plus je crois que non*** have the very same meaning.

To state a disagreement, the reply will likely use *si* or something similar, e.g.:

> *– Je crois qu'elle viendra, au contraire.*

or

> *– Moi je crois que si.*

or simply

> *– Moi, si !*

Answer (score 0):

I would say

> Moi aussi

intuitively, but it feels like one of these situations where it might be ambiguous no matter how you respond.

However, if the dialogue was

> A: Marie va venir ce soir?
>
> B: Je ne crois pas.

Then I'd gravitate towards:

> Moi non plus.

- meaning: "I don't believe so either".

So, it looks like the response will refer to "je crois/je ne crois pas" more than to the "oui/non" that follows. Which makes sense: A says how she behaves, i.e. believing or not believing (that Marie will come).